# Mongoose and Node.js multi tenant architecture

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, mongoose, multi-tenant

I am building an app that uses a multi tenant architecture as follows

**User architecture**

- tenant_name: Name of the user
- tenant_id: ObjectID

**Multi tenant DB**

mongoose schema

- widget: Data for widget
- Area: location for widget
- Tenant_identifier: ObjectID from user architecture

**API**

I have implemented the login using webtokens and i am able to identify the logged in user etc. What is the best implementation of the API such that it returns only the records in multi tenant DB based on the tenant_id.

Can i write an access layer that filters the data in the API server or should i pass the objectID in the findBy routine of mongoose. I am looking for some design patterns for implementation.

I am using DaftMonks Generator as a starting point https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add the ObjectId to the queries and *not* filter the data after you retrieved it from the database.

Using the ObjectId as extra query condition (which is implicitly *AND*'ed with any other conditions that you query for) will not only limit the amount of data that the database will have to return, but with proper indexes in place it will also be pretty fast.

Comment: Ok, is the objectId filter used in the multi-tenant-db.find call or as a hook in pre find?

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa I don't see how you could use it in a hook (because hooks are applied system-wide). So yeah, you'd use it on `.find*` calls.

Comment: Hmm.. i thought there should be a better way in a middleware or another layer. How would i architect admin and super admin roles who have the privilege to view all ids..

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa perhaps you can use [`mongoose-access-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-access-plugin)?

Comment: that seems an interesting way to do access control. will take a look at that.